# scheme, continued-fraction, tail-recursion

Tags: scheme, tail-recursion, continued-fractions

As a scheme-newbie I'm trying to solve some basic problems.
One of them are continued fractions, which I like to realize both ways, recursively and via tailrecursion.
My recursive soloution (d and n are functions and k is the recursion-depth):

```
(define (c-fraction d n k)
  (if (= k 0) 1 
      (/ (n k) (+ (d k) (c-fraction d n (- k 1))))))
```

is working like I want to, but I've no idea, how to makte this tail-recursively.
 I do not to recognize, which expression I have to to accumulate in which way.

Answer (score 0):

Remark that your function computes:

```
n_k / (d_k + n_{k - 1} / (d_{k - 1} + ...
```

If you want to compute

```
n_1 / (d_1 + n_2 / (d_2 + ...
```

you need to reverse the order of the coefficients:

```lisp
(define (c-fraction2 d n k)
  (c-fraction
    (lambda (x) (d (+ 1 (- k x))))
    (lambda (x) (n (+ 1 (- k x))))
    k
  )
)
```

For a tail-recursive function you just need to keep:

```
n_k / (d_k + n_{k + 1} / (d_{k + 1} +
```

in the accumulator, without the need to reverse the coefficients:

```lisp
(define (c-fraction-tail d n k acc)
  (if (= k 0)
    acc
    (c-fraction-tail
      d
      n
      (- k 1)
      (/ (n k) (+ (d k) acc))
    )
  )
)
```

The expressions `(c-fraction2 d n k)` and `(c-fraction-tail d n k 1)` give the same results.

Comment: Yes, I'd seen already, that it is neccesary to reverse the coefficients, but up to that time I tested it only with constant functions (f.e. (d 1) (n 1)).<br>
The rest is much more easier as I thought, my thinking was to complicated.
It is very instructive to recognize, that there is no need to reverse the coefficients
when using the tailrcursion.

Thank you verry much,<br>
Peer